# logs and metric values don't match

Tags: google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-monitoring

I'm trying to configure an alert for a log based metric in Google Cloud Monitoring. In my sample time frame, there are two log entries I'm interested in.

Using the metrics explorer, I build a query for the metric, but the values in the metric explorer don't make sense. For the first entry the metric explorer shows a value of 4, and for the second log entry, there are two bars one with a value of 1 and one with a value of 2.

It doesn't make any sense! Does anyone know how to properly configure this?

this is how it shows in metrics explorer
[image: metrics explorer]

and this is the underlying data
[image: underlying data]

note my local time is UTC+3 hence the timestamp offset.

Comment: Can you provide more details ? I mean what's your goal ? Do you want to have a chart the will show you how many occurences the metric counted in a given period of time ?

Comment: my goal is to have the chart show the data that is in the logs. In this example log entries appear at 3:52 and 4:20 (timestamp adjusted to match chart screenshot). I expect a bar of value 1 for the period 3:50-3:55 (5 min interval as shown in screenshot) and a bar with value 1 at 4:20-4:25 but instead I have 3:50-3:55 = 4 / 4:15-4:20=1 / 4:20-4:25=2

Comment: This shouldn't happen. From your description it looks everything's working. Try filtering out the logs again and create another metric.

Comment: OK I figured out how to make this work as I expected. I changed the aligner under advanced aggregation to "Delta" and now the chart values match. Using delta also allows the creation of an alert of the form "alert when this log entry appears more than 10 times in one day" and the alert will disappear when the number of entries is < 10 in a rolling previous 24 hours. Would still be interested to know what an aligner of count is actually showing, but for my use case it doesn't matter.

Comment: @crazystick you can put it as an answer